# How to add class in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML element with `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="{new: item.new}"></div>
```

I need if `item.new` is true then add class `new`

Comment: You have already written the correct syntax. What's the problem?

Comment: That looks like it works to me http://plnkr.co/edit/4n9RQHbVV8aRtsxC7kyC?p=preview

Comment: My guess is that `item.new` is evaluating to false.

Comment: No, `item.new` is true. Maybe problem is that exists attribute class `class="notif-item"`

Comment: For me also does not work expression: `ng-show="currentCount.notifications >0"`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<div ng-class="{'new': item.new}"></div>
```

You need to put class name in quotes.

Comment: This is not true: http://plnkr.co/edit/4n9RQHbVV8aRtsxC7kyC?p=preview

Comment: You ounly need to put the class name in quotes if it contains characters that would require quotes around it in a JS object key.

Comment: your answer is wrong..i will work without `'` single quote, you shouldn't be added that answer